# Woocommerce add custom checkbox field in cart item and save it in order

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

my project is..

I want to add a checkbox  **ONLY** in every cart item in cart page (**NOT in single product page like add_before_add_to cart_button**), so that the customer can select if the product is for gift..like the photo

[cart item in cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfaKX.jpg)

..and also display the value in checkout page and in order details...

after a lot of searches i do something like this...but only display the checkboxes in cart item..not save..not displayed in order...

where am i wrong?? Can you help me?

```
 * Add a text field to each cart item
 */
function prefix_after_cart_item_name( $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) 
{

 ?>
            <div class="simple-selects">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="gift" id="gift"><?php _e( " Wrap as Gift", "aoim");?></p>
                </div>
            </div>  <?php
 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', 'prefix_after_cart_item_name', 10, 2 );


/**
         * Add data to cart item
         */
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
        function add_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {

            if ( isset( $_POST ['gift'] )) {
                /*$custom_data  = array() ;
                $custom_data [ 'gift' ]    = isset( $_POST ['gift'] ) ?  sanitize_text_field ( $_POST ['gift'] ) : "" ;
                $cart_item_meta ['custom_data']     = $custom_data ;*/
                $cart_item_data[ 'gift' ] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['gift']);

            }

            return $cart_item_data;
        }
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_idvopros_as_order_meta', 10, 3 );
function save_idvopros_as_order_meta( $order_id, $data ) {
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item)
        $gift = empty($cart_item['gift']) ? 'yes' : $cart_item['gift'];
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_idvopros_temp', $gift, true);
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'ustanovka_oplaty');
function ustanovka_oplaty( $order_id) {

    $gift = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_idvopros_temp', true );
    if ( ! empty( $gift ) ) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'wpcf-idvopros', $gift );
        delete_post_meta($order_id, '_idvopros_temp' );
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question again? You're trying to save whether it's checked or not as part of the order metadata? Is that right?

Comment: Yes.. that's what I want..